# How to prove the relation between dimensions of linear subspaces and their vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces, induction

If $H_1, ... , H_k$ are linear subspaces of $V$ with $k≤n$, so that each $H_i$ has the dimension $n-1$.

How can I prove that $dim(H_1 \cap ... \cap H_k) ≥ n-k$?

I have a feeling this might be doable with the help of induction, but cannot really formulate how to set up the problem.

Comment: $\dim U + \dim W = \dim (U + W) + \dim (U \cap W)$ and induction works.

Comment: Thanks a lot @DanielFischer! How would I set up the induction? I'm a little lost here.

Comment: If you look at what you want to prove, don't you get an idea which subspaces you should use for $U$ and $W$?

Comment: But, how can I prove for example that they are distinct? For the above statement to be true, they have to have at least one linearly independent vector, right?

Comment: Think about what happens if they aren't distinct. If, say, $H_5 = H_2$. Then what? Is there any problem? (No, there is no problem. It may just not be easy to see that there is no problem.)

Comment: Ok, let's say i set up the induction as follows: $dim(H_i)+dim(H_{i+1}) = dim(H_{i}\cap H_{i+1})+dim(H_{i}+H_{i+1})$ and want to prove the first step.
How can I calculate the right hand side of this equation if I don't know where they intersect?

Comment: You know there are only two possibilities for $\dim (U+ H_{i+1})$, whatever subspace $U$ is. And that's all that you need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48570/discussion-between-void-and-daniel-fischer).